# Tab Bar in Iphone Programming?

Tags: iphone, tabbar

I make an application using Tab Bar.
I have 2 views controller: View1 and View2 and a RootViewController.
In RootViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Tab Bar"];
    View1 *vc1 = [[View1 alloc]init];
    View2 *vc2 = [[View2 alloc]init];

    [vc1.tabBarItem setTitle:@"View1"];
    [vc2.tabBarItem setTitle:@"View2"];

    [self setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil]];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

When I build application, I have an error: Have a white place. When I go to View 2 and back to View 1 it is disappeared. I want to delete white place. Please see image in here: [http://photo.ssc.vn/images/108Screen_Shot_2013_08_18.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HejOL.jpg)
Thanks for your helping!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue when adding view controllers to a tab bar.

The solution is to set `wantsFullScreenLayout` on the `UINavigationController` to NO, so it won't even attempt to leave that gap for the status bar.

[Apple says](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) :

> Tab bar controllers support full-screen layout differently from the
>   way most other controllers support it. You can still set the
>   wantsFullScreenLayout property of your custom view controller to YES
>   if you want its view to underlap the status bar or a navigation bar
>   (if present). However, setting this property to YES does not cause the
>   view to underlap the tab bar view. The tab bar controller always
>   resizes your view to prevent it from underlapping the tab bar.

For more detailed explanation you can see this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183834/uinavigationcontroller-within-viewcontroller-gap-at-top-of-view?rq=1).

Comment: @user2678221 : In satckoverflow , we mark that right tick beside the answer (Accept the Answer) to say "thanks" :)